# Tcp needed when i2c and ssh are used?

Tags: c, tcp, raspberry-pi, i2c, psoc

I'm doing a project where I have 2 raspberry pi zeros connected and a psoc 5 connected to one of the rpi's.

The connection between them are all i2c. 
One of the rpi's are considered the "master" and from my android phone I will use ssh to remote control the master.

```
[Phone] = SSH = [RPi Master] = I2C = [RPi Slave]
                               ||
                            [PSOC 5]
```

My teacher told me to consider tcp/ip, but I will still have the 2 rpi's and the psoc connected by wires.

My question therefore is - are there any benefits in doing tcp in my project?

Comment: Let's step back a minute. Why are there two separate Raspberry Pis in your project?

Comment: @duskwuff because we stream PiCam on the 1. one and it uses too much of the capacity, so we cannot put the other codes/programs in the same pi. I know that the rpi 3 could solve the problem, but we are not allowed to use other rpi's other than the rpi zero.

Answer (score 0):

There is no clear way to answer whether TCP is better than I2C without more info about your project, as that is an application-specific question. This question would be easier to answer with a little more detail on your project, including requirements, data rates, etc., but I will try to give you some info based on personal experience.

The only reason to consider TCP/IP between the devices is if the data rate needed is higher than I2C can support, or if it would be useful to keep them separated beyond I2C range.

Creating a program that utilizes TCP to run on your phone and the master would make the system a little more complete, as you would have a program running on the master constantly to automatically accept information from the user and run the commands, rather than having to control it from the command line. This would also force you to create some sort of user-facing program for the phone. From a design perspective for a class project, this could be preferable.

Without knowing why your teacher suggested that it is hard to give you a straight answer; it is possible the suggestion was given not for any real performance reasons but for you to learn about networking, TCP/IP protocols, or to be able to say you have "IoT experience".